# Creating matrix with the same vector in each row

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have `p = [1,2,3,4]`. I would like a 100x4 numpy matrix with `p` in each row. What's the best way to create that?

I tried `pvect = np.array(p for i in range(10))` but that doesn't seem to be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
pvect = np.tile(p, (100, 1))
```

output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       ...
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using matrix algebra: the multiplication of a column vector of ones times your row vector `p` effectively places the vector `p` in each row.

```
p = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
OutputArray = np.ones((100, 1)) @ p
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```py
pvect = np.array(p*100).reshape((100,4))
```

Comment: I'm confused: I thought p*100 would be scalar multiplication not duplication.

Comment: @Smithey if `p` is a python list, this will duplicate it (not with a numpy array though)

Comment: the thing is `p = [1,2,3,4]` is not an array but a list and `p*100` is just multiplying 100 times the same list

Comment: I see so for scalar multiplication you need np.array(p)*scalar. Gottit thanks!